# Heroes 7 - Arcane knowledge use after 8

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-7

In heroes 7 (I think it was actually introduced in 6... not sure, been a while) you have 1 stat called arcane knowledge.

Its use is pretty straight forward: to learn spells lvl 2 you need 2 arcane, for 3 you need 5 and for 4 you need 8 arcane knowledge.

My question is... after you reached 8 is there any use to lvl it up more? So far I found none but especially on campaign is pretty easy to hit 8 on magic classes (even in multiplayer is rather easy) so maybe I'm missing something.